# How to turn off button shadow on button press of UIButton?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uibutton, shadow

I've created a UIButton in InterfaceBuilder.  When a user presses the button, the entire button is shaded grey.  Is there a way to alter this behavior so the button is no longer shaded grey when the button is pressed?

Comment: Is it a custom button or a default button? Try unchecking "Highlighted Adjusts Image" in IB.

Answer (score 31):

Uncheck "Highlighted Adjusts Image" in Interface Builder.

Alternatively, set the `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` property of the `UIButton` to `NO`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the button type to custom from system in the attributes inspector of the button